# How reliable is the paper loading mechanism in Epson R1900?

Tags: printing

I have an Epson Stylus Photo 1400, that could print up to A3+, but the paper loading mechanism has been designed by idiots: only one roll placed at the extreme right margin. that means it's good in printing 4" x 6" pictures, but, when printing something bigger than A4, it will skew the sheet: no surprises here, with only one pinch roll placed at the extreme right margin, it's impossible to load a 17" wide sheet without let it skew.

So, since I did not buy this printer to print 4R pictures, I want to get rid of that, and buy an Epson R1900. Unfortunately, no store has this in stock, I have to order it online. Anyone has this printer and can tell me how the pinch roll is made?

Comment: When it comes to printing on role paper, the only devices that I've seen do that **well** are the commercial-grade Epson and Canon (and HP, even) printers.

Comment: I hate printers.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an R1900 for about 2 years, and have printed roll paper in both 8.3" and 13" widths, and 13x19 sheets with no problems,